# Remove few HTML Tags while pasting the data from the clipboard in Tinymce

Tags: html, tinymce, clipboard, paste

I'm using Tinymce 2.2 and i need to remove few HTML tags while pasting the data in the tinymce textarea.

I have the data in format:

```
<DIV id="testId"> ABCD </DIV>
```

On paste event, when I use `window.clipboardData.getData("Text")`to get the data, I only get `"ABCD"` and I need the whole data `<DIV id="testId"> ABCD </DIV>`

Where and how can I get this whole HTMLdata in tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').getContent();
```

Ref : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent